# Subdomain under Apache to proxy into Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, subdomain, ajp

I'm having trouble with making a subdomain to my Windows computer while using AJP to proxy to Tomcat. This is what I have in my httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName subdomain.localhost  
    ProxyRequests Off  
    <Proxy *>  
        Order deny,allow  
        Allow from all  
    </Proxy>  
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/folder/  
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/folder/  
    <Location />  
        Order allow,deny  
        Allow from all  
    </Location>  
</VirtualHost>
```

The subdomain has been added to `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>   127.0.0.1       subdomain.localhost

When I go to `http://localhost` i goes straight to the proxy. When I go to `http://subdomain.localhost` i goes to the proxy as well. How do I make is so the subdomain only goes to the proxy and the regular goes to Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a second VirtualHost with localhost as the ServerName.

Comment: Learn something new everyday :)

Comment: can you post an example of what the second VirtualHost should look like?

Comment: Same as the one in the question, but with ServerName localhost instead of ServerName subdomain.localhost

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be moved to superuser.com but one thing to try:

`<VirtualHost *:80`> informs it to accept all incoming connections on port 80 to use these settings. I would try changing it to say:

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.localhost:80>
```

and see if that only applies these settings when the subdomain is used.

The ServerName tag that you put with the subdomain doesn't tell it who to listen for. The official documentation states:

> The ServerName directive sets the
>   hostname and port that the server uses
>   to identify itself. This is used when
>   creating redirection URLs. For
>   example, if the name of the machine
>   hosting the web server is
>   simple.example.com, but the machine
>   also has the DNS alias www.example.com
>   and you wish the web server to be so
>   identified, the following directive
>   should be used:

You can read more on these configurations [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: I tried the subdomin.localhost before and it was still going straight to the tomcat from localhost. Thanks for a response and the link to superuser.com I'll try to distinguish my questions from site to site from today forward.